# Duplicate Components with Unique Args in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Usually, when using one component, my story looks like this:

```
export const Template = args =>{
    return (
      <Dropdown {…Dropdown.args}>
    )
}

Dropdown.args = {dropdownOptions: [] }
```

However, I'm now attempting to repeat a component with unique properties for each instance.

```
export const Template = args =>{
    return (<div>
      <Dropdown {…First.args}>
      <Dropdown {…Second.args}>
</div>)
}

First.args = {dropdownOptions: [] }
Second.args = {dropdownOptions: [] }
```

While I'm not getting errors in my code, this does break the page. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Hey there! Would you be able to share the piece of code where you define First and Second?

Comment: I don't currently. What's the best way to define them in this scenario?

Comment: I've added an example of how I usually do it with only one component.